# Failure to quick build pdfs using Texmaker 3.3.4 and Miktex 2.9, both portable

Tags: miktex, texmaker

I'd be grateful for advice regarding a failure to quick build `.pdf`s, using a set-up consisting of portable Texmaker 3.3.4 and portable MiKTeX 2.9. I got this set-up by following the instructions [here](http://jimstitzel.com/2010/01/configuring-texmaker-usb-with-miktex-portable/), and put it on my hard drive (booted with 64-bit Win 7 Pro SP1) as well as on a USB flash drive. The problem is that no `.pdf` is built when I press <kbd>F1</kbd>. I get the problem when using the Win 7 laptop, but not when using the flash drive on another laptop booted with 32-bit Win XP Pro SP2.

With a simple `.tex` file I get no messages and the following logfile:

```
> LOG FILE : This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (MiKTeX 2.8)
> (preloaded format=pdflatex 2011.9.28) 2 OCT 2011 21:25 entering
> extended mode
> **ams*template.tex ("C:\Documents and Settings\han3user\Desktop\latex stuff\ams template.tex" LaTeX2e <2009/09/24> Babel <v3.8l> and
> hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge rman,
> ngerman, german-x-2009-06-19, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, french, loaded.
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\ams\classes\amsbook.cls"
> Document Class: amsbook 2009/07/02 v2.20.1 \linespacing=\dimen102
> \normalparindent=\dimen103 \normaltopskip=\skip41 ("C:\Program
> Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\ams\math\amsmath.sty" Package: amsmath
> 2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features \@mathmargin=\skip42 For additional
> information on amsmath, use the `?' option. ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
> 2.8\tex\latex\ams\math\amstext.sty" Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\ams\math\amsgen.sty" File:
> amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 \@emptytoks=\toks14 \ex@=\dimen104 ))
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\ams\math\amsbsy.sty" Package:
> amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d \pmbraise@=\dimen105 ) ("C:\Program
> Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\ams\math\amsopn.sty" Package: amsopn
> 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names ) \inf@bad=\count79 LaTeX Info:
> Redefining \frac on input line 211. \uproot@=\count80
> \leftroot@=\count81 LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line
> 307. \classnum@=\count82 \DOTSCASE@=\count83 LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 379. LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line
> 382. LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 467. \Mathstrutbox@=\box26 \strutbox@=\box27 \big@size=\dimen106 LaTeX Font
> Info: Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 567. LaTeX Font
> Info: Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 568.
> \macc@depth=\count84 \c@MaxMatrixCols=\count85 \dotsspace@=\muskip10
> \c@parentequation=\count86 \dspbrk@lvl=\count87 \tag@help=\toks15
> \row@=\count88 \column@=\count89 \maxfields@=\count90
> \andhelp@=\toks16 \eqnshift@=\dimen107 \alignsep@=\dimen108
> \tagshift@=\dimen109 \tagwidth@=\dimen110 \totwidth@=\dimen111
> \lineht@=\dimen112 \@envbody=\toks17 \multlinegap=\skip43
> \multlinetaggap=\skip44 \mathdisplay@stack=\toks18 LaTeX Info:
> Redefining \[ on input line 2666. LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input
> line 2667. ) LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for U+msa
> on input line 367. ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
> 2.8\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd" File: umsa.fd 2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols A ) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
> 2.8\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty" Package: amsfonts 2009/06/22 v3.00 Basic AMSFonts support \symAMSa=\mathgroup4 \symAMSb=\mathgroup5
> LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version
> `bold' (Font) U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 96. )
> \copyins=\insert233 \abstractbox=\box28 \listisep=\skip45
> \c@part=\count91 \c@chapter=\count92 \c@section=\count93
> \c@subsection=\count94 \c@subsubsection=\count95 \c@paragraph=\count96
> \c@subparagraph=\count97 \c@figure=\count98 \c@table=\count99
> \abovecaptionskip=\skip46 \belowcaptionskip=\skip47
> \captionindent=\dimen113 \thm@style=\toks19 \thm@bodyfont=\toks20
> \thm@headfont=\toks21 \thm@notefont=\toks22 \thm@headpunct=\toks23
> \thm@preskip=\skip48 \thm@postskip=\skip49 \thm@headsep=\skip50
> \dth@everypar=\toks24 ) \c@thm=\count100 ("C:\Documents and
> Settings\han3user\Desktop\latex stuff\ams template.aux") LaTeX Font
> Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 132. LaTeX Font
> Info: ... okay on input line 132. LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults
> for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 132. LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input
> line 132. LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input
> line 132. LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 132. LaTeX Font
> Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 132. LaTeX Font
> Info: ... okay on input line 132. LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults
> for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 132. LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input
> line 132. LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input
> line 132. LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 132. LaTeX Font
> Info: Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 132.
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd" File:
> umsa.fd 2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols A ) LaTeX Font Info: Try loading
> font information for U+msb on input line 132. ("C:\Program
> Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd" File: umsb.fd 2009/06/22
> v3.00 AMS symbols B ) [1{C:/Documents and Settings/All
> Users/Application Data/MiKTeX/2.8/pdftex/con fig/pdftex.map}]
> ("C:\Documents and Settings\han3user\Desktop\latex stuff\ams
> template.aux") ) Here is how much of TeX's memory you used: 1378
> strings out of 495285 15401 string characters out of 3180325 66922
> words of memory out of 3000000 4459 multiletter control sequences out
> of 15000+200000 9695 words of font info for 38 fonts, out of 3000000
> for 9000 175 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191 34i,4n,31p,249b,166s
> stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s <C:/Program
> Files/MiKTeX 2.8/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><C:/Prog
> ram Files/MiKTeX
> 2.8/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmcsc10.pfb><C:/Program Fil es/MiKTeX 2.8/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb><C:/Program
> Files/MiKTe X
> 2.8/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.8/fo nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.8/fonts/type1 /public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.8/fonts/type1/public/a msfonts/cm/cmr5.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.8/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm /cmr7.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.8/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pf b><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.8/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb><C:/Pro gram
> Files/MiKTeX 2.8/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb><C:/Program
> Fil es/MiKTeX 2.8/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msam10.pfb>
> Output written on "ams template.pdf" (1 page, 127020 bytes). PDF
> statistics: 54 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607) 0 named
> destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000) 1 words of extra memory for PDF
> output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

With a more sophisticated .tex file which uses more packages, I get the messages:

```
> ! Package Listings Error: Couldn't load requested aspect.See the
> Listings package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for
> immediate help.... \lst@RequireAspects\lst@loadaspects
> 
> ! LaTeX Error: File `datetime.sty' not found.Type X to quit or
> <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter
> file name:! Emergency stop.<read > \renewcommand
> 
> ! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

and the logfile:

```
> LOG FILE : This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (MiKTeX 2.9)
> (preloaded format=pdflatex 2012.6.26) 26 JUN 2012 20:19 entering
> extended mode
> **Project*2_1.tex ("C:\Users\han7user\Desktop\!CP stuff\Project 2_1\Project 2_1.tex" LaTeX2e <2009/09/24> Babel <v3.8l> and
> hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar abic,
> (snip)
> ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, u senglishmax, welsh, loaded.
> ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\base\article.cls"
> Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
> ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\base\size10.clo" File:
> size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option) )
> \c@part=\count79 \c@section=\count80 \c@subsection=\count81
> \c@subsubsection=\count82 \c@paragraph=\count83
> \c@subparagraph=\count84 \c@figure=\count85 \c@table=\count86
> \abovecaptionskip=\skip41 \belowcaptionskip=\skip42
> \bibindent=\dimen102 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex/latex\geometry\geometry.sty" Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex/latex\graphics\keyval.sty" Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC) \KV@toks@=\toks14 ) ("C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty" Package: ifpdf
> 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO) Package ifpdf Info:
> pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected. ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex/generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty" Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO) Package ifvtex Info:
> VTeX not detected. ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex/generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty" Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional ) \Gm@cnth=\count87 \Gm@cntv=\count88
> \c@Gm@tempcnt=\count89 \Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103 \Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104
> \Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105 \Gm@even@mp=\dimen106 \Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107
> \Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108 \Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109
> \Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110 \Gm@dimlist=\toks15 ("C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\geometry\geometry.cfg")) ("C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\listings.sty" Package: listings 2002/04/01
> 1.0 (Carsten Heinz) \lst@mode=\count90 \lst@gtempboxa=\box26 \lst@token=\toks16 \lst@length=\count91 \lst@currlwidth=\dimen111
> \lst@column=\count92 \lst@pos=\count93 \lst@lostspace=\dimen112
> \lst@width=\dimen113 \lst@newlines=\count94 \lst@lineno=\count95
> \c@lstlisting=\count96 \lst@maxwidth=\dimen114 ("C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\lstpatch.sty" File: lstpatch.sty 2002/10/13
> 1.0i (Carsten Heinz) ) ! Package Listings Error: Couldn't load requested aspect. See the Listings package documentation for
> explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help. ... l.1820
> \lst@RequireAspects\lst@loadaspects The following aspects weren't
> loadable:
> ,strings$,comments$,escape$,style$,language$,keywords$,labels$,lineshape$,f
> rames$,emph$,index$ This may cause errors in the sequel. )
> ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\base\textcomp.sty"
> Package: textcomp 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package Package
> textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information: (textcomp) 5 = only ISO-Adobe
> without \textcurrency (textcomp) 4 = 5 + \texteuro (textcomp) 3 = 4 +
> \textohm (textcomp) 2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency (textcomp)
> 1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t (textcomp) 0 = TS1 (full) (textcomp) Font
> families with sub-encoding setting implement (textcomp) only a
> restricted character set as indicated. (textcomp) Family '?' is the
> default used for unknown fonts. (textcomp) See the documentation for
> details. Package textcomp Info: Setting ? sub-encoding to TS1/1 on
> input line 71. ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex/latex\base\ts1enc.def" File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file ) LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums
> on input line 266. Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to
> TS1/0 on input line 281. Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss
> sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 282. Package textcomp Info:
> Setting cmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 283. Package textcomp
> Info: Setting cmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 284. Package
> textcomp Info: Setting cmbr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 285.
> Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input
> line 286. Package textcomp Info: Setting ccr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on
> input line 287. Package textcomp Info: Setting ptm sub-encoding to
> TS1/4 on input line 288. Package textcomp Info: Setting pcr
> sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 289. Package textcomp Info:
> Setting phv sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 290. Package textcomp
> Info: Setting ppl sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 291. Package
> textcomp Info: Setting pag sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 292.
> Package textcomp Info: Setting pbk sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line
> 293. Package textcomp Info: Setting pnc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 294. Package textcomp Info: Setting pzc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on
> input line 295. Package textcomp Info: Setting bch sub-encoding to
> TS1/4 on input line 296. Package textcomp Info: Setting put
> sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 297. Package textcomp Info:
> Setting uag sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 298. Package textcomp
> Info: Setting ugq sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 299. Package
> textcomp Info: Setting ul8 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 300.
> Package textcomp Info: Setting ul9 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line
> 301. Package textcomp Info: Setting augie sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 302. Package textcomp Info: Setting dayrom sub-encoding to
> TS1/3 on input line 303. Package textcomp Info: Setting dayroms
> sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 304. Package textcomp Info:
> Setting pxr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 305. Package textcomp
> Info: Setting pxss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 306. Package
> textcomp Info: Setting pxtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 307.
> Package textcomp Info: Setting txr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line
> 308. Package textcomp Info: Setting txss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 309. Package textcomp Info: Setting txtt sub-encoding to
> TS1/0 on input line 310. Package textcomp Info: Setting futs
> sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 311. Package textcomp Info:
> Setting futx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 312. Package textcomp
> Info: Setting futj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 313. Package
> textcomp Info: Setting hlh sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 314.
> Package textcomp Info: Setting hls sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line
> 315. Package textcomp Info: Setting hlst sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 316. Package textcomp Info: Setting hlct sub-encoding to
> TS1/5 on input line 317. Package textcomp Info: Setting hlx
> sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 318. Package textcomp Info:
> Setting hlce sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 319. Package textcomp
> Info: Setting hlcn sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 320. Package
> textcomp Info: Setting hlcw sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 321.
> Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcf sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input
> line 322. Package textcomp Info: Setting pplx sub-encoding to TS1/3 on
> input line 323. Package textcomp Info: Setting pplj sub-encoding to
> TS1/3 on input line 324. Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmx
> sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 325. Package textcomp Info:
> Setting ptmj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 326. ) ("C:\Program
> Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty" Package:
> amsfonts 2009/06/22 v3.00 Basic AMSFonts support \@emptytoks=\toks17
> \symAMSa=\mathgroup4 \symAMSb=\mathgroup5 LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting
> math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold' (Font) U/euf/m/n -->
> U/euf/b/n on input line 96. ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex/latex\ams\classes\amsthm.sty" Package: amsthm 2004/08/06 v2.20 \thm@style=\toks18 \thm@bodyfont=\toks19 \thm@headfont=\toks20
> \thm@notefont=\toks21 \thm@headpunct=\toks22 \thm@preskip=\skip43
> \thm@postskip=\skip44 \thm@headsep=\skip45 \dth@everypar=\toks23 )
> ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\ams\math\amsmath.sty"
> Package: amsmath 2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
> \@mathmargin=\skip46 For additional information on amsmath, use the
> `?' option. ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex/latex\ams\math\amstext.sty" Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\ams\math\amsgen.sty"
> File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 \@emptytoks=\toks24 \ex@=\dimen115 ))
> ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\ams\math\amsbsy.sty"
> Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d \pmbraise@=\dimen116 ) ("C:\Program
> Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\ams\math\amsopn.sty" Package: amsopn
> 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names ) \inf@bad=\count97 LaTeX Info:
> Redefining \frac on input line 211. \uproot@=\count98
> \leftroot@=\count99 LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line
> 307. \classnum@=\count100 \DOTSCASE@=\count101 LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 379. LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line
> 382. LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 467. \Mathstrutbox@=\box27 \strutbox@=\box28 \big@size=\dimen117 LaTeX Font
> Info: Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 567. LaTeX Font
> Info: Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 568.
> \macc@depth=\count102 \c@MaxMatrixCols=\count103 \dotsspace@=\muskip10
> \c@parentequation=\count104 \dspbrk@lvl=\count105 \tag@help=\toks25
> \row@=\count106 \column@=\count107 \maxfields@=\count108
> \andhelp@=\toks26 \eqnshift@=\dimen118 \alignsep@=\dimen119
> \tagshift@=\dimen120 \tagwidth@=\dimen121 \totwidth@=\dimen122
> \lineht@=\dimen123 \@envbody=\toks27 \multlinegap=\skip47
> \multlinetaggap=\skip48 \mathdisplay@stack=\toks28 LaTeX Info:
> Redefining \[ on input line 2666. LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input
> line 2667. ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex/latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty" Package: amssymb 2009/06/22 v3.00 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\ltxmisc\url.sty"
> \Urlmuskip=\muskip11 Package: url 2006/04/12 ver 3.3 Verb mode for
> urls, etc. ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex/latex\tools\enumerate.sty" Package: enumerate 1999/03/05 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC) \@enLab=\toks29 ) ("C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\tools\array.sty" Package: array 2008/09/09
> v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi) \col@sep=\dimen124
> \extrarowheight=\dimen125 \NC@list=\toks30 \extratabsurround=\skip49
> \backup@length=\skip50 ) ! LaTeX Error: File `datetime.sty' not found.
> Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed, or enter new name. (Default
> extension: sty) Enter file name: ! Emergency stop. <read *> l.17
> \renewcommand
> *{\noon}{\unskip\pmname}
> *** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes) Here is how much of TeX's memory you used: 2864 strings out of 494053 37453 string
> characters out of 3146170 87194 words of memory out of 3000000 6169
> multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000 3640 words of font
> info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000 715 hyphenation exceptions
> out of 8191 27i,0n,28p,227b,49s stack positions out of
> 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s ! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output
> PDF file produced!
```

Everything works fine on my XP laptop, both using an earlier portable version of Texmaker and non-portable MiKTeX on the hard drive, and using the above-mentioned set-up on the flash drive. One thing I have tried is to copy the `miktex\tex\latex` folder from the XP laptop, which contains far more packages, including `listings`, to the Win 7 one - but to no avail.

Many thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: Obviously you have a problem with listings. But you will have to make and show us a small but complete tex-file that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I think your local pdflatex engine is running in both examples. Normally when you run the pdflatex from USB/Flashdrive, it should pick the executable from N:/miktex/miktex/.../pdflatex.exe. Check with a simple minimum working example on machine where there is no local miktex distro

Comment: Thanks. I've now installed the non-portable versions instead, changing the problem somewhat, so will close this thread. (Edit: none of the available reasons for closure seem appropriate, so I've left it open.)